# How to generate multi class test dataset using numpy?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, random, classification, knn

I want to generate a multi class test dataset using numpy only for a classification problem.
For example X is a numpy array of dimension(mxn), y of dimension(mx1) and let's say there are k no. of classes. Please help me with the code.
[Here X represents the features and y represents the labels]

Comment: Check out [make_classification](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_classification.html) from scikit-learn. You can specify the size of arrays and number of classes in that, and also they will be somewhat appropriate. It doesnt meet your demand of only numpy as you have to install scikit-learn, but internally it still uses numpy. So maybe you can make something out of the source code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.random.randint` like:

```
import numpy as np
m = 4
n = 4
k = 5
X = np.random.randint(0,2,(m,n))

X
array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 0, 0],
   [1, 1, 1, 1]])

y = np.random.randint(0,k,m)

y
array([3, 3, 0, 4])
```

Comment: I tried this but this is a bit too random. I need to generate points for multi class. Like some points will represent a class or group and they should be near each other. By near I mean the Euclidean distance. For eg. you're testing KNN algorithm with this dataset but since it doesn't represent the classes properly so you can't use it.

Comment: I don't understand your requirements, maybe you can clarify what kind of output you are expecting.

Comment: Something like this https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/mlc-downloads/downloads/submissions/62061/versions/3/screenshot.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You can create multi class dataset using numpy as follows -

```
def generate_dataset(size, classes=2, noise=0.5):
    # Generate random datapoints
    labels = np.random.randint(0, classes, size)
    x = (np.random.rand(size) + labels) / classes
    y = x + np.random.rand(size) * noise
    # Reshape data in order to merge them
    x = x.reshape(size, 1)
    y = y.reshape(size, 1)
    labels = labels.reshape(size, 1)
    # Merge the data
    data = np.hstack((x, y, labels))
    return data
```

When visualised with matplotlib generated data will look like following -
[image: multi class data]

You can change the number of classes and spread of data using `classes` and `noise` parameter. Here I have kept linear relation between x-axis and y-axis values which can also be changed as per requirement.